# Can I disable the Magento Inventory modules?

Tags: magento2, module, inventory, msi

I have my stock synchronized and managed by SAP, because of it I'm having issues with the inventory quantity vs salable quantity, I won't use multi-source inventory in this project,

can I disable all the Magento_Inventory modules and not have issues?

```
    'Magento_Inventory' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryAdminUi' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryAdvancedCheckout' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryApi' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryBundleProduct' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryCatalog' => 1,
    'Magento_InventorySales' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryCatalogApi' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryConfiguration' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryElasticsearch' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryExportStockApi' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryIndexer' => 1,
    'Magento_InventorySalesApi' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryImportExport' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryCache' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryProductAlert' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryRequisitionList' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryReservations' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryReservationCli' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryReservationsApi' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryExportStock' => 1,
    'Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryGraphQl' => 1,
    'Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi' => 1,
    'Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryShipping' => 1,
    'Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi' => 1,
    'Magento_InventorySourceSelection' => 1,
    'Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi' => 1,
    'Magento_SalesInventory' => 1,
    'Magento_ScalableInventory' => 1,
    'Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi' => 1,
    'Magento_CatalogInventoryStaging' => 1,
```

Comment: Check this two. https://github.com/yireo/magento2-replace-all and best solution to add in composer and best for composer https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/remove-msi-modules-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the modules that you have installed disabling all the `Magento_Inventory` modules might cause issues, so I recommend installing this module below to disable the stock reservation.

```
composer require ampersand/magento2-disable-stock-reservation
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento module:enable Ampersand_DisableStockReservation
```

> **Both the inventory and cataloginventory_stock should be in the same mode** (Update on Save or Schedule) for this module to work as expected.
>
> If you are running this on Schedule you should have CRONs activated.

This module will:

- Prevent all writes to the inventory_reservations table. It does so by using an `around` plugin on `PlaceReservationsForSalesEventInterface`
- Trigger stock deductions on order placement. See `inventory_sales_source_deduction_processor` observer on `sales_order_save_after` event.
- Prevent stock deductions on order shipment. See disabled `inventory_sales_source_deduction_processor` observer on `sales_order_shipment_save_after` event.
- Replenish stock for cancelled order items. See `inventory` observer on `sales_order_item_cancel` event.

## Alternative

If you have just few third-party modules and you're sure that disabling is not causing issues you can just run this command below to disable all `Magento_Inventory` modules.

```
php bin/magento module:status | grep Magento_Inventory | grep -v List | grep -v None | grep -v -e '^$' | xargs php bin/magento module:disable
```

Answer (score 1):

## Magento Inventory (MSI) documentation

Source Management - https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/inventory-sources.html

Stock to Source assignment - https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/inventory-about-sources-stocks.html

Reservations - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/inventory/reservations.html

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/inventory-about-order-status-reservation.html

Source Selection Algorithm - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/inventory/source-selection-algorithms.html

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/inventory-about-ssa.html

Order workflow diagrams - https://github.com/magento/inventory/wiki/Salable-Quantity-Calculation-and-Mechanism-of-Reservations#description-of-order-processing

https://github.com/magento/inventory/wiki/Shipment-and-Order-Management

MSI + Backorder - https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/inventory-backorders.html

This will help you to better understanding.